# Is there a method to avoid the overhead caused by clear_page_emrs() in the kernel?

Tags: security, optimization, memory-management, linux-kernel

I followed [this method](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) and found that `clear_page_erms` generated a significant amount of overhead in the flame graph.

After searching the Internet, I learned that the purpose of this function is to zeroize pages allocated by the kernel during page fault. Considering that my workload is not a multi-tenant cloud environment and there will be no malicious software or attack behavior, **can I control the kernel to relax these security features and bypass this reset operation to improve performance?**

I am using kernel 5.14, AMD processor, and do not enable huge pages or transparent huge pages.

The relevant kernel parameters are all not set:

```
#
# Memory initialization
#
CONFIG_INIT_STACK_NONE=y
# CONFIG_INIT_ON_ALLOC_DEFAULT_ON is not set
# CONFIG_INIT_ON_FREE_DEFAULT_ON is not set
# end of Memory initialization
# end of Kernel hardening options
# end of Security options
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. While it obviously has security implications, zeroing out pages is not just a security feature, it is a well-defined basic functionality of the kernel. A normal system cannot correctly work without the kernel zeroing out pages before making them available to userspace, as userspace programs will expect them zeroed out.

If you have a custom kernel compiled with `CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED=y`, then userspace programs can explicitly opt-out of automatic page initialization by passing `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` to `mmap`, but that's about it.

Regardless though, even having `CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED=y` isn't really going to do much on any normal system as a whole, since normal programs usually never pass that flag and expect zeroed out memory after `mmap`. In the context of a single application though it may help and make a significant difference.

Comment: These two compilation macros (`CONFIG_INIT_ON_ALLOC_DEFAULT_ON` and `CONFIG_INIT_ON_FREE_DEFAULT_ON`) should also control normal page fault situations. In my flame graph, the function call relationship is as follows: do_user_addr_fault -> handle_mm_fault -> ... -> do_anonymous_page -> ... -> get_page_from_freelist -> prep_new_page -> kernel_init_free_pages.part.74 -> clear_page_erms. The call to `kernel_init_free_pages` is controlled by `want_init_on_free` and `want_init_on_alloc`, which in turn controled by `CONFIG_INIT_ON_ALLOC_DEFAULT_ON` and `CONFIG_INIT_ON_FREE_DEFAULT_ON`.

Comment: @Frontier_Setter you are right, either I missed it or did not know. They also control page not only kernel memory heap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the man page for `mmap(2)`, on how to configure the kernel to take into account the `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` flag:

> `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` (since Linux 2.6.33)
>
> - Don't clear anonymous pages. This flag is intended to improve performance on embedded devices. This flag is honored only if the kernel was configured with the `CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED` option. Because of the security implications, that option is normally enabled only on embedded devices (i.e., devices where one has complete control of the contents of user memory).

I.e. you'll need a custom built kernel for which you put

```
CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED=y
```

into its `.config` file (or set it through menuconfig). For this to take hold in your user space applications, you'll have to pass this flag to all relevant calls of `mmap`.

Take note though, that not initializing memory can in fact have a negative impact on performance, specifically increased latency imposed by the delayed population of page tables. So it's a double edged sword.

Comment: *"increased latency imposed by the delays population of page tables"* - what do you mean by this exactly? Not zeroing out new pages on fault shouldn't really have any effect on the population of page tables.

Comment: Is there a method to achieve this effect without recompiling the kernel or modifying the code?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It's not so much about zero at page fault, but at memory not being (pre-) faulted at all. Speaking from personal experience here. It took me quite some development effort implementing the high speed (>20GB/s) de-fragmenting free-list allocator for our realtime OCT imaging and acquisition systems. One key development here was the mechanism for pre-faulting pages quickly.

Comment: @datenwolf ah, I see. That is weird though, AFAIK `mmap`'d pages are never pre-faulted anyway. You would need `MAP_POPULATE` for that.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Yes, mmap doesn't prefault by default. Which is fine for most programs. However for the systems I develop it's not. And the semantics of `MAP_POPULATE` make this one also unacceptably slow. Some of our imaging systems have >1TiB of RAM, and there the semantics that are imposed on `MAP_POPULATE` make it take well over a minute to complete. The pre-faulter in my allocator finishes initialization of ~1TiB in well under 5 seconds. Just writing this out to excuse me for not mentioning `MAP_POPULATE` (I don't use it :-) ).